# Ruby on Rails reset value back to null

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following were my view:

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <%= f.select(:require_booking, get_advance_booking.collect {|p| [ p[:require_booking], p[:require_booking] ] }, {include_blank: false} , :class => 'form-control') %>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-3">
    <%= f.text_field :require_days, :class => 'form-control advance-booking', :placeholder => 'How many days?', :disabled=>true%>
</div>
```

And here is my `application_helper.rb`

```
  def get_advance_booking
    ret = [{:require_booking => 'Yes'},{:require_booking => 'No'}]
  end
```

Following were my `product.rb` model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
enum require_booking: {
        No: 0,
        Yes: 1
    }
end
```

Now the Issues is if I select an option of `Yes` the text field will be enabled and user can enter value. In edit mode, if I select an option `No` how can I set the text field value back to `NULL` and save to db? Currently, even though I set the value `NO` I still get my previously set value. Thanks!!

Comment: you should use javascript since it is client logic.

Answer (score 0):

You only can do that with javascript changing the value field of select.

Example:

Supose that your code generate the following html:

```
<input type="select" value="Yes"></input>
<input type="text" value="EditValue"></input>
```

For solve this question you need a javascript(jQuery) code like this:

```
 $("input[type='select']").change(function() {
     $("input[type='text']").val(' '); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you cant assign Null value to the form input. You can set it to be empty '' . But that wouldn't not be helpful in your case. The possible solution for you is to disable the field when 'No' is selected. Disabled input value would not be submitted in form. So the base case would be handled. 
But if you are updating than you can handle it on the backend. You can add before filter.

```
before_filter: check_for_require_days

def check_for_require_days
  params.merge!(require_days: nil) unless params[:require_days].present? 
end
```

This would check if the value is disabled than it would not be in the form params so it would set it to null.

Answer (score 0):

Just add **:onchange => "$('#product_require_days').val('')"** to your "require_booking" select

```
<%= f.select(:require_booking, get_advance_booking.collect {|p| [ p[:require_booking], p[:require_booking] ] }, {include_blank: false} , :class => 'form-control'), :onchange => "$('#product_require_days').val('')" %>
```